# Why tap even is fired before click on touch screen device in jQueryMobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have noticed that click event is fired **before** tap in all major desktop browsers. But on Android 2.3 emulator it is the tap event that comes first.

Here is the test page: [bit.ly/jqmctap](http://bit.ly/jqmctap)

Why tap even is fired before click on touch screen device in jQueryMobile? And why is it different on desktop?

jQueryMobile: 1.0.1, jQuery: 1.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think on desktop browsers the tap event will be started from the click event, because it isn't normally needed on desktops. On touch screen browsers the tap event comes first, because it's intended for the use with touch screens, because only there you can really tap on the screen. Than it starts the click event, for compatibility to web pages, which need the click event.